# Conversão de "query" um formulário HTML usando .htaccess

Tags: php, html, htaccess, apache

Necessito fazer uma conversão de uma "query" de um formulário HTML que deve passar informações para fazer um pesquisa no banco de dados.
Penso que poder ser algo parecido com um tipo de "url amigável", dos mais simplórios.

Básicamente é, com essa string passada pelo formuláro "*?category=html&year=2017*" para algo assim "*/category/html*" ou "*/year/2017*".

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso com o "*.htaccess*", porém não sei **COMO** fazer.

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Por questão de arquivamento.*

Segundo o artigo
[How To Rewrite URLs with mod_rewrite for Apache on Debian 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-debian-8), é possível fazer essa mudança na URL através do *mod_rewrite* do Apache.

A resolução, no arquivo *.htaccess*, seria a adição desta regra:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&year=$2 [QSA]
```